# using Redis as primary database

Tags: javascript, database, express, redis

**I am writing a chat application in node js express js, can we make such a mongodb query in redis database?**
I'm trying to use hscan and hvals for the query, but if anyone has an idea, can it help?

```
const msg = await messageModel.findOne({
        $or: [{
                $and: [{
                    senderId: {
                        $eq: myId
                    }
                }, {
                    reseverId: {
                        $eq: fdId
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                $and: [{
                    senderId: {
                        $eq: fdId
                    }
                }, {
                    reseverId: {
                        $eq: myId
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }).sort({
        updatedAt: -1
    })
```

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: @hoangdv so what kind of query should i write , i am trying to fetch the latest messages in my application

Comment: What version and flavor of Redis are you using? If you're using a version that can support RediSearch, it can do these sorts of queries.

Comment: could you add at the beginning of the your code   the relevant "import" or "require" modules ?

Comment: thanks ı will use rediSearch i installed the module now